# Swipe down update from Firebase in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to make update of my RecyclerViewer with data from Storage for profile picture and Firestore for other data. But I tried many methods and I don't know how to make this.
The goal is to make a RecyclerViewer update each time user goes to fragment and also be able to swipe to refresh the list. Also the layout gets inflated after second 'visit' on the Fragment, the first time it does not get inflated. Is this a problem with a Glide?
And the cache keeps the data in RecyclerViewer even when new user is logged in with completely different data in Firebase.

#### fragment_item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/itemContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FriendFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.msmmhm.hauimetyourmother.FriendFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".FriendFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

#### FriendFragment.kt

```
imports ...

class FriendFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentItemListBinding
    private lateinit var  mSwipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = FragmentItemListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        with(binding.list) {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = MyFriendRecyclerViewAdapter(Friend.ITEMS,container!!.context)

            return binding.root

        }

    }

}
```

#### MyFriendRecyclerViewAdapter.kt

```
imports ...

class MyFriendRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private val values: List<FriendItem>,
    val context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyFriendRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        return ViewHolder(
            FragmentItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = values[position]
        var events: CollectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("events")
        val docRef = events.document(item.id)
        Log.i(ContentValues.TAG,"EVENTS ITEM ID: "+item.id)
        docRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document.exists())
                {
                    Log.i(ContentValues.TAG,"DOCUMENT EXISTS")
                    val map = document.data
                    if (map!!.size != 0)
                    {
                        holder.activeIcon.setColorFilter(R.drawable.presence_online)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        holder.activeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.presence_invisible)
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    holder.activeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.presence_invisible)
                }
            }
        holder.friendNickname.text = item.friendName

        loadWithGlide2(item.id,holder)

    }


    fun loadWithGlide2(id: String, holder: ViewHolder) {
        val storageReference = Firebase.storage.reference.child("ProfilePictures/${id}.jpg")
        Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "NAME IS: ${storageReference.name}")

        Glide.with(context)
            .load(storageReference)
            .error(R.drawable.defaultprofilepicture)
            .into(holder.friendImg)
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int = values.size

    inner class ViewHolder(binding: FragmentItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val friendImg: ImageView = binding.friendPicture
        var friendNickname: TextView = binding.friendNickname
        var activeIcon: ImageView = binding.activeIcon
        val itemContainer: View = binding.root

        override fun toString(): String {
            return super.toString() + " '" + friendNickname.text + "'"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to wrap `RecyclerView` in a `SwipeRefreshLayout` ...

Comment: The whole ```ConstraintLayout``` is wraped in it. And the 'swipe' move works but I could't find a way to properly load Fireabse and Storage data.

Comment: So you want to track when the user swipes the entire layout?